# Focus distance when tracking

Tags: canon, nikon

Using a large aperture lens and focus tracking (or repeated re-focus operations) do any cameras provide subject speed and/or distance?

Comment: "Provide" in what sense? Viewfinder information? EXIF info? Internal calculations?

Comment: @michael  In any sense other than measuring the position of the focus ring on the lens.  I want to get this information quickly (within one second) and preferably automatically and electronically for external processing..

Comment: This sounds like law enforcement territory - speed cameras and the like.  I'd suggest checking with suppliers of that sort of equipment.  There's a free add-on for many Canon Powershot models called CHDK which might allow you to script something yourself to get something like you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Some cameras (most Nikons) provide distance information if you are using a modern lens.  The information is very approximate, such that it is only usable for a gross idea of distance. I am not aware that the camera turns its tracking into any sort of speed information in EXIF though in theory multiple images over time would let you calculate that from distance change, but again the distance information provided is very gross and I would expect to be unusable for speed calculations other than the most rudimentary and probably only for fast speeds as I do not think the distance information is very fine grained. The information is available quickly on the card but getting it out (say with Wifi) within 1 second is also unlikely.  I think what you really need for this is a true distance measuring device, and trying to use a regular DSLR for it is not viable at all from EXIF information.

Comment: Very informative.  I will pursue other methods.

Comment: There exist "range finder binoculars". Google that.

Comment: I have one.  The old style works by an angle of view scale, which you place over a known-height thing (e.g. building on a shoreline), and read off a chart the result - from trig, not from phase detection distance measuring that a DSLR uses..  The newer ones are usually laser distance measuring devices combined with the optics.  Neither of which seem relevant to using a DSLR.